# Same Token for both web and installed apps (Google Calender API V3)

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a web application that creates Events on Google calender and keeps a refresh token in the database. In parallel, I have another desktop application that needs to fetch these events and update them, using this already saved refresh token. 
Now, when I try to use the same Refresh token, that was saved by the web application, in my desktop app, it doesn't fetch any events...as if the Refresh Token is invalid.
Can I use the same refresh token both on the installed and web apps? Am I doing something wrong here?